# Euler series with milder divergence

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

Theorema 19 in Euler's memoir "Variae observationes circa series inﬁnitas" says

> The sum of the reciprocals of the prime numbers is inﬁnitely great but is inﬁnitely times less than the sum of the harmonic series. And the sum of the former is as the logarithm of the sum of the latter.

In modern terms ($p$ denotes a prime number) 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k\le n}\frac{1}{k}-\ln{n}\right )=\gamma_1,$$ 
and
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{p\le n}\frac{1}{p}-\ln{\ln{{n}}}\right )=\gamma_2,$$
where $\gamma_1\approx 0.5772156649$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant and $\gamma_2\approx 0.2614972128$ is the Mertens Constant.

Can we extend this further? That is can we indicate a subseries of the harmonic series whose sum is "inﬁnitely times less" than the sum of the Euler series and "equals" the logarithm of the sum of the latter:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k(with\,some\,condition\,on\,it)\le n}\frac{1}{k}-\ln{\ln{{\ln{n}}}}\right )=\gamma_3?$$

Comment: Integers of the form $\lfloor n \log{n} \log\log{n}\rfloor$ should do.

Comment: Maybe primes of order of primality, i.e such that the smallest $m$ such that the $m$-the iterate of the prime counting function, is at least equal to $2$.

Comment: Interestingly, the sum of reciprocals of the super-primes (prime-index primes) converges to $\sim 1.04$, see pp.10-12 in the article A43 in  http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/vol13.html (New Bounds and Computations on Prime-Indexed Primes, by J. Bayless, D. Klyve, and T.O. e Silva).

Comment: How about primes with a prime number of digits?